# Função não reconhece valor modificador por ela

Tags: javascript

Olá, pessoal.

No código abaixo, ao tentar mudar o valor da variável `horasAula` da função `Professor` através da função `setHorasAula` e o valor da variável `cargo` da função `Coordenador`, o valor que imprime na tela é `undefined`, ao invés do novo valor. As outras funções get e lecionando funcionam perfeitamente.

```
function Funcionario () {
    var nome;
    var matricula;
    var sexo;
    var dataNascimento;
    var salario;

    this.getNome = function () {
        return this.nome;
    };
    this.setNome = function (nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    };
    this.getMatricula = function () {
        return this.matricula;
    };
    this.setMatricula = function (matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    };
    this.getSexo = function () {
        return this.sexo;
    };
    this.setSexo = function (sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    };
    this.getDataNascimento = function () {
        return this.dataNascimento;
    };
    this.setDataNascimento = function (dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    };
    this.getSalario = function () {
        return this.salario;
    };
    this.setSalario = function (salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    };
    this.receberSalario = function () {
        return "Recebendo salário..."
    }
}

function Professor () {
    var horasAula;

    this.getHorasAula = function () {
        return horasAula;
    };
    this.setHorasAula = function (horasAula) {
        this.horasAula = horasAula;
    };
    this.lecionar = function () {
        return "Lecionando...";
    };
}

function Coordenador () {
    var cargo;

    this.getCargo = function () {
        return cargo;
    };
    this.setCargo = function (cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    };
    this.criarTurma = function () {
        var turma = {};
    };
} 

Professor.prototype = new Funcionario();
Professor.prototype.constructor = Professor;
Coordenador.prototype = new Professor();
Coordenador.prototype.constructor = Coordenador;

var fun = new Funcionario();
var prof = new Professor();
var coord = new Coordenador ();

fun.setDataNascimento(07081994);
console.log(fun.getDataNascimento());

prof.setNome("ola");
console.log(prof.getNome());
prof.setHorasAula(18);
console.log(prof.getHorasAula());

coord.setCargo("Auxiliar de Representante Ajudante Administrativo");
console.log(coord.getCargo());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ficou faltando o comando **this** antes da variável que você deseja retornar no método get.

```js
this.getHorasAula = function () {
  return this.horasAula;
};
```